# Android image/video slider library

Tags: java, android, slider

im creating an android app allows user to find a place (Restaurant for example) , tha app has a home page displayed and images and videos slider.

Im looking for an android library that offers images and videos slider.

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: Did you find any library?

Comment: No sir,i have developed a custom image/video slider based on an image slider (Daimajia).

Answer (score 4):

You can try [PosterSlider](https://github.com/mohan-dev1248/PosterSlider).

It's useful for both image and video slider. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MediaSliderView](https://github.com/Zeuskartik/MediaSliderView)

GoodLuck.